# How do I ask a Ruby method to use a member variable?

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, call, member

I have this Ruby class:

```
class Drive

    attr_accessor :pitch, :ring, :sprocket, :links

    def initialize pitch,ring,sprocket,links
        @pitch = pitch
        @ring = ring
        @sprocket = sprocket
        @links = links
    end

    def teeth2radius choice
        return ((pitch * choice) / (Math::PI * 2));
    end

    def ring2sprocket
        return ((pitch / 8) * ((2 * links - ring - sprocket) + Math.sqrt(((2 * links - ring - sprocket) * (2 * links - ring - sprocket)) - (8 / (Math::PI * Math::PI)) * (( ring - sprocket) * ( ring - sprocket)))))
    end

end
```

I would like to call the teeth2radius method by passing it something like the -name- of one of the two member variables.  Like this:

```
teeth2radius :ring

  -OR-

teeth2radius :sprocket
```

The Drive object contains them both, I just want to call it with one or the other.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The idea of classes and methods is encapsulation, the member variables are an implementation detail, you normally should not expose them to your method interfaces.

Comment: Why do you define getters and then circumvent them?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`instance_variable_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get)

Using this method, in your function you can use:

```
def teeth2radius choice
    return ((pitch * instance_variable_get("@#{choice}")) / (Math::PI * 2));
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I can now call it with :ring or :sprocket.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def teeth2radius choice
    choice = method(choice).call # or: choice=instance_variable_get("@#{choice}")  
    return ((pitch * choice) / (Math::PI * 2));
end
```